# Nginx not serving on the domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have installed nginx on a VM (OS: Ubuntu 18). I am following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) but the issue is that I am not able to see the content getting served on your_domain.com. Here's my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Files in **sites-enabled** and **sites-available** directory: default your_domain
your_domain (both in sites-enabled and sites-available)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/your_domain/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name your_domain.com www.your_domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**index.html** file in `/var/www/your_domain/html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to your_domain!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success!  The your_domain server block is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lastly, this is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 your_domain.com (trying out)
35.188.213.229 your_domain.com (trying out)
10.128.0.48 your_domain.com (trying out)
```

I am not sure where the issue is because whenever I open your_domain.com, it says  the following in chrome browser

> This site can’t be reached
> your_domain.com’s server IP address could not be found.

I have tried doing traceroute your_domain.com as well:

> traceroute: unknown host your_domain.com

Tried nginx in macOS, it works there but I need to set it up in ubuntu VM for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Given that traceroute is unable to resolve host name into ip address, I suppose that problem is caused by your /etc/hosts or some other issues with name resolution process on client side.

Most probably linux resolver library is unhappy with `()` in lines. Try removing them, keeping statement as clean as possible - e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1 your_domain.com
```

Note - this thing may be cached, so you may also need to restart your browser after making changes.

On MacOS you may even need to flush system-level dns cache:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache && killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: Yep I'm not using (), put them here just to explain. But do you think running nginx server block on VM, i should give the IP address this 127.0.0.1 and not the primary IP address of my VM?

Comment: Depends on which /etc/hosts we are speaking about and how your vm is connected to your hosts.

On vm itself, it's ok and even advisable to have 127.0.0.1 - if you wish your http client on vm to be able to reach your nginx no-matter-what. Basically if `curl http://your_domain.com` on vm gives you correct page - your nginx is almost certainly tuned correctly.

On host system - if your VM is hidden behind nat (and not pingable on it's ip), _and_ you've created tcp forwarding rules to forward some ports into vm - it is also ok.

Comment: If your vm is bridged to the same network as your host (and thus you can ping it's ip address from host), on the other hand - you should use that ip address instead of 127.0.0.1